# How to manipulate à DataGrid in Silverlight 3

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I having trouble to manipulate CeLLs content in Silverlight Grids...
I can get my DataGrid, the Columns but not the Cell value.

How can I get the first Cell wich is an Image in a Button for every row??
I can only achieve my goal by events like the button_click but not in regulare code behind.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataGrid.SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditem(VS.95).aspx) property and cast record to your desired object.

```
Customer c = GrdCustomers.SelectedItem as Customer;
if (c != null)
{
    string customerId = c.CustomerID;
}
```

assuming you have your datasource as Customer.

Comment: @Polo: Thanks for pointing out. I have updated my response, let me know if this doesnt help.

Comment: DataGrid.SelectedItem is already cast as a XmlProduct in my project that isn't the problème.
Let say for Product.ID == 1 i want to get the distinct row in my grid to change the little picture in Columns[0].Cell[0].Content. How can I do that?